# How to fix a column of serial number in table while other columns are dynamic? Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, html-table

I'm having a LEADERBOARD table with 5 columns in it. I'm able to auto-sort(i.e. top scorer on the top of the table) the table with **SCORE**(column 5) of a user with a script. but when table auto-sorted the Serial Number(column 1) also altered. I want to use first column to display the **RANK** of a user so it must be like 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on. But it keep changes as score of a user varies.

Here is the table structure:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Gravatar</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Score</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="searchable">
@if(count($visitors)>0)
    @foreach($visitors as $key=>$visitor)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$key+1}}</td>
            <td><img style="border-radius: 50%" width="50px" height="50px" src="{{ Gravatar::src($visitor->email) }}"></td>
            <td>
                <a href="/profile/{{$visitor->id}}">
                    {{$visitor->name}}
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{$visitor->branch}}</td>
            <td>{{$visitor->rank_score}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@else
    <td>No User at this time.</td>
@endif
</tbody>
```

Here is Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       
       $('#userTable').DataTable({

            "order": [4, 'rank_score'],

       });
   });
```

If first column display fix serial number then I can use it to display rank.

Thanks.

Comment: can you include your sort script?

Comment: script is working fine and gives the required result.

Comment: maybe this helps? you can add the `table.on` part to your script. [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/index_column.html)

Comment: Its working now, thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the rank with php in your blade view, by using the key in the for loop. You must first sort your visitors array by the rank score, then display them with the loop.
Ideally this is done in your database with an order by clause, or you could do it in your view:

```
@foreach($visitors->sortByDesc(‘rank_score’)->values() as $key=>$visitor)
```

The `values()` resets the keys after sorting which you need.

With the JavaScript you can then use the rank and the order column (ascending).